# Update stripe subscription billing_cycle_anchor = now and retry schedule

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm manually restarting a subscription via the Stripe API when a volume exceeds. We have complex plan and tiers so it can't be done with built in Stripe features. 
This is done via 
`https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update` and setting `{ "billing_cycle_anchor": "now" }`. When a card declines it returns error `{ "code": "card_declined" }` and the subscription restart fails.

In the normal process of recurring payments with subscriptions a failed payment yields into *Retry schedule*.

Can I force this *Retry schedule* after setting `{ "billing_cycle_anchor": "now" }` or do I need to handle retries manually?